# Vim: text indent long line by comma, not breaking quoted values?

Tags: vim, indentation

You have a long list and you want to indent it by the comma so that values do not break up in the middle, to be more readable.

```
indent = ['11111_1111111111111111','11111_111111111111111111','11111_1111','11111_111111111111111','11111_1111111111111111',\ #Indentation should look something like this, preferably to width of the editor.
        '11111_111111111111111','11111_111111111111','11111_1111111111111111111111','11111_111111111111111111111111','11111_1111111111111111111111111',\
        '1111_12_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111','1111_12_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111111111',\
        '1111_12_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_1111','1111_12_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111111','1111_12_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111',\
        '1111_12_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111111','1111_12_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111','1111_12_11111_1111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111111',\
        '1111_12_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111111111','1111_12_11111_1111111111111111_11111_1111','1111_12_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111111',\
        '1111_12_11111_1111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111','1111_12_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111111','1111_12_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111',\
        '1111_13_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111','1111_13_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111111111','1111_13_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_1111',\
        '1111_13_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111111','1111_13_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111','1111_13_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111111',\
        '1111_13_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111','1111_13_11111_1111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111111','1111_13_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111111111',\
        '1111_13_11111_1111111111111111_11111_1111','1111_13_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111111','1111_13_11111_1111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111',\
        '1111_13_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111111','1111_13_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111',\
        '1111_14_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111111111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_1111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111111',\
        '1111_14_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111111_11111_111111111111',\ #HOW TO INDENT the following like the above?
        '1111_14_11111_1111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111111111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111_11111_1111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111_11111_1111111111111111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111111','1111_14_11111_1111111111111111_11111_111111111111','11141_11111_111111111111111','11141_11111_111111111111111111','11141_11111_1111111111111111111','11141_11111_111111111111','11141_11111_1111111111111111','11141_11111_1111','11141_11111_111111111111111','11141_11111_1111111111111111','11141_11111_11111111_71111','11141_11111_11111111_141111','11141_11111_11111111_211111','11141_11111_11111111_11111111111111111','11141_11111_111111111111111','11141_11111_111111111111111111','11141_11111_1111111111111111111','11141_11111_111111111111','11141_11111_1111111111111111','11141_11111_1111','11141_11111_111111111111111','11141_11111_1111111111111111','11141_11111_11111111_71111','11141_11111_11111111_141111','11141_11111_11111111_211111','11141_11111_11111111_11111111111111111','11181_11111_111111111111111','11181_11111_111111111111111111','11181_11111_1111111111111111111','11181_11111_111111111111','11181_11111_1111111111111111','11181_11111_1111','11181_11111_111111111111111','11181_11111_1111111111111111','11181_11111_11111111_71111','11181_11111_11111111_141111','11181_11111_11111111_211111','11181_11111_11111111_11111111111111111','11181_11111_111111111111111','11181_11111_111111111111111111','11181_11111_1111111111111111111','11181_11111_111111111111','11181_11111_1111111111111111','11181_11111_1111','11181_11111_111111111111111','11181_11111_1111111111111111','11181_11111_11111111_71111','11181_11111_11111111_141111','11181_11111_11111111_211111','11181_11111_11111111_11111111111111111','111161_11111_111111111111111','111161_11111_111111111111111111','111161_11111_1111111111111111111','111161_11111_111111111111','111161_11111_1111111111111111','111161_11111_1111','111161_11111_111111111111111','111161_11111_1111111111111111','111161_11111_11111111_71111','111161_11111_11111111_141111','111161_11111_11111111_211111','111161_11111_11111111_11111111111111111','111161_11111_111111111111111','111161_11111_111111111111111111','111161_11111_1111111111111111111','111161_11111_111111111111','111161_11111_1111111111111111','111161_11111_1111','111161_11111_111111111111111','111161_11111_1111111111111111','111161_11111_11111111_71111','111161_11111_11111111_141111','111161_11111_11111111_211111','111161_11111_11111111_11111111111111111']
```

**How can I indent a long line on a non-quoted comma in Vim?**

Comment: Something like `%s/\v('\w+',){4}\zs/\r        /g` would need some cleaning up but gets the job almost done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim does not take syntax into account.

As a workaround, you can either:

- Do it manually, depending of each use case; for example, for your sample text, because there is no space at all, you can take profit of the `gq` command; you could do the following while being on the last long line:

  ```
  :s/,/, /g
  gql
  :'[,']s/$/\\
  ```

  Then manually fix what still looks wrong; (note: the above code was not greatly tested, it may not work for you, depending on `'textwidth'`, `'formatoptions'`...)
- Use an external formatter. I don't know which language your sample text is (the ending backslashes let me wonder about it), but let's consider for the example that it is some python code.
  First install a plugin like [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/chiel92/vim-autoformat). It will help you to integrate existing external formatters in your system into Vim.
  Then install a language-specific formatter. If you're using python, [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) may already have been installed.
  If you want to format only a part of your file, copy the desired part into a new buffer, and run:

  ```
  :setf python
  :set textwidth=100   " <-- set the text width as you wish
  :Autoformat
  ```

  Your buffer will be wrapped in a smart way. Many options are available, depending of the external formatter.